# How to process an array which is bound to a control with promises in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise

Let us assume we have a component defined in AngularJS. Let's name it `UserList`. The component has property, so controller can pass an array of users to the component.

```
<user-list users="arrayOfUsers"></user-list>
```

Markup of user list contain input - where users are listed, and a button. On button click component should be able to process user list.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.users" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.process()">
            Process users
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Seems to be a piece of cake, but it's not when user processing entail calls to web service, and promises.

If we'd just iterate over array of users, and call web service to process the user it won't work because result won't be returned immediately, but executed in asynchronous way.

```
this.userList.forEach(function (part, index, array) {
    var userName = array[index];
    UserService.processUser(userName).then(function (result) {
        array[index] = result; //not so easy...
    });
});
```

But actually how should the array be iterated to handle the promises properly?

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve exactly

Comment: @ABOS To simplify the real problem - I want to process an array (which is bound to input control) using web service. Each item should be updated during the processing. So when user clicks the button then the program iterates over the array, each iteration causes call to the web service, and after all iterations, when all calls are done the array (and input) should be changed, processed in some way.

Comment: what is the difficulty?

Comment: make array of promises, then use $q.all